Lefschetz fixed point theorem-type formula for a finite group acting on a Fredholm operator
Let $D:X\to Y$ be a Fredholm operator, so that its index $\dim\ker (D)-\dim \text{coker}(D)$ is defined. We can view $D$ as a complex $\mathfrak{D}:0\to X\xrightarrow{D} Y\to 0$, and for a chain map $T:\mathfrak{D}\to \mathfrak{D}$, i.e. a commutative diagram $\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X @>{D}>> Y\\
@V{T}VV @V{T}VV\\
X @>{D}>> Y
\end{CD}
there are induced maps $T_0:\ker(D)\to \ker(D)$ and $T_1:\text{coker}(D)\to\text{coker}(D)$. The Lefschetz number $L(T)$ of $T$ is defined by $L(T)=\text{trace}(T_0)-\text{trace}(T_1)$. Note that if $T=\text{id}$ then $L(T)=\text{ind}(D)$.
Now suppose there is a finite group $G$, linearly acting on both $X$ and $Y$, and giving chain maps $g:\mathfrak{D}\to \mathfrak{D}$ for each $g\in G$. Let $X^G$ and $Y^G$ be the fixed point sets (which are linear subspaces) of $X$ and $Y$, respectively; then $D$ restricts to a well-defined map $D^G:X^G\to Y^G$. Is it true that its index $\text{ind}(D^G)$ is equal to the average $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G} L(g)$ of the Lefschetz numbers? I want to know a brief sketch of its proof.
